# Jquery iterating through JSON array

Tags: jquery, json, gwt

I created a function that listens to inputs and prints out a message when input fields are updated. Previously my code looked like this:

HTML

```
<div class="meta">@name</div>
<div class="meta">@date_today</div>

<div id="meta"></div>
```

NOTE: @ is used in GWT as a shorthand for `<input type="text">`, so it's basically the same thing. It also works as `input.value()` if used in js script.

Js function:

```
var $meta = $('#meta');
var _meta = $('.meta input');
var message = "form updated";

var createNarrative = function (section, element, txt) {
    section.change(function() {
        element.show().html(txt)
    });
}

createNarrative(_meta, $meta, message);
```

Now I need to update the function so that all the function arguments will be moved to JSON file.

```
 var json = [
            {
                "section": "$('#meta')",
                "input": "$('.meta input, .meta select')",
                "output": "Form Updated"
            }
        ]

function(data){
        $.each(index, object){
            var section = object.section;
            var input = object.input;
            var output = object.output;
        }

        input.change(function() {
            section.show().html(output)
        });
    };
}
```

However, this function responses with error. As I'm working in GWT, debugging is a bit difficullt. I can't figure out why it's not working.

Comment: Where is the variable `object` defined ? at a first glance I woul say it has to be `json` instead

Comment: Where in GWT does `@` mean `<input type="text"/>`? That doesn't sound familiar at all... Are we talking about the same GWT, that compiles Java to JavaScript?

Comment: @colin Yes, Google Web Tools. I'm not sure, this might be as well feature of a certain project, but we use @ that compiles to input. By default it's text field, though it can be as well set to textarea, select, radio, etc.